# Help installing WIFI USB adapter from Alfa, model AWUS036AC on Ubuntu 15.4

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I recently purchased the WIFI USB adapter from Alfa, model AWUS036AC.  I downloaded the latest Linux driver from their website AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902, but unfortunately being a beginner to Linux, I have no idea how to install it and there are no real instructions.  The pc I am trying to install this adapter is running a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.4.

The Windows installation went fine so I know the adapter is good and the pc hardware can see it.
I run a Non-Profit organization named Omnilink Education and Training Group.

We take donated PCs from individuals and businesses and refurbish them, install Edubuntu Linux and place them in schools in low income areas for free.

This way we help keep older pcs from the junk pile and provide educational aids where they are most needed. Edubuntu is a gift from heaven because of its ease of use to the young users and because of the incredible amount of free educational software and low maintenance.  Our organization would not exist without it, as we tried with a Windows based system and it was way beyond our finances.  We are relatively new to Ubuntu, so our chops do not go much beyond basic use yet.  We are trying to go wireless wherever we can as it is cheaper than running network cables.

We are trying this adapter in low signal areas and for administrative uses where speed is more important.

Any help world be most appreciated.
    In behalf of us all
    Thank you!
        osvaldo (omnilinktg@gmail.com)

```
ozzie@ozzie-MS-7693:~$ lsusb 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
ozzie@ozzie-MS-7693:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.4 is discontinued ?, you should upgrade. Maybe that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 and install a driver for this dongle by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

You need to be connected to internet before you run this command.

Comment: Excellent. I can confirm this works on Ubuntu 16.04 with a AWUS036AC USB dongle.